# Safari: Mysterious frame after performing complex layout

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari, rendering

Here's a situation for someone who's expert in browser rendering details. It's very specific, so I hope someone is willing to take the time to help me out.

---

I have encountered a strange situation where a mysterious frame is rendered in Webkit, after I've done some complex layout routine. As this doesn't happen in Chrome, it *might* be a Webkit bug, but perhaps someone here can see if I'm doing something wrong.

In big lines, this is the outline of the application:

1. There are two 'layers' (`base` & `overlay`)
2. There is a transition between them when I click on the page.
3. When I'm scrolled down a bit, in Safari, just before the transition, the base layer jumps up to the top, and back again:

[image: Jitter]

However, if I'd draw a timeline of my code and where this bug occurs, it's like this:

`|-- L1 -- R -- L2 -- ❌ -- ✅ -- ...|`

Where:

- `L1`: Layout code
- `R`: Forced reflow
- `L2`: Layout code
- ❌: Incorrect frame
- ✅: Correct frame

In other words, the incorrect frame is rendered and corrected by the browser, without any of my code interfering. However, the incorrect frame is a *result* of some of the code I'm executing in `L1` (if I remove some of the layout code, the bug disappears).

I've created a fiddle with the code: https://jsfiddle.net/joostlubach/5eruf12k/. However, ironically the bug doesn't appear there, probably because jsfiddle wraps everything in a container.

I've also added a [ZIP file](http://www.joostlubach.com/Mysterious%20Frame.zip) with the source code, and a screen capture of Safari and Chrome, illustrating the problem.